# Voltdb init encountered an unrecoverable error and is exiting

Tags: init, configure, voltdb

I followed the official documents about voltdb, but encounter a error when using

```
voltdb init --config=deployment.xml
```

init voltdb configure file.
and the error is

```
ERROR: Deployment information could not be obtained from cluster node or locally
VoltDB has encountered an unrecoverable error and is exiting
The log may contain additional information.
```

my voltdb version is **voltdb-community-8.0**

about the log file volt.log:

```
2018-05-02 08:52:25,048   INFO  [main] HOST: PID of this Volt process is 15950
2018-05-02 08:52:25,062   INFO  [main] HOST: Command line arguments: org.voltdb.VoltDB initialize deployment deployment.xml
2018-05-02 08:52:25,063   INFO  [main] HOST: Command line JVM arguments: -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=300 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=3600 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseCondCardMark -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775807 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=9223372036854775807 -XX:CMSWaitDuration=120000 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=120000 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/voltdb/log4j.xml -Djava.library.path=default
2018-05-02 08:52:25,064   INFO  [main] HOST: Command line JVM classpath: /usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/voltdb/voltdb-8.0.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/vmetrics.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jetty-io-9.3.21.v20170918.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jetty-server-9.3.21.v20170918.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jline-2.10.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jsch-0.1.51.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/slf4j-nop-1.6.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/httpcore-4.3.3.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/felix.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jetty-util-9.3.21.v20170918.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.21.v20170918.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jetty-security-9.3.21.v20170918.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/scala-library-2.11.5.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/owner-1.0.9.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/owner-java8-1.0.9.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/snmp4j-2.5.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jetty-continuation-9.3.21.v20170918.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/httpclient-4.3.6.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jna.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jetty-http-9.3.21.v20170918.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/httpasyncclient-4.0.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/httpcore-nio-4.3.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/commons-lang3-3.0.jar:/usr/local/voltdb-community-8.0/lib/extension/voltdb-rabbitmq.jar
2018-05-02 08:52:25,064   ERROR [main] HOST: Deployment information could not be obtained from cluster node or locally
```

so, it lead to can't generating configure file. Please tell me what means about the **"Deployment information could not be obtained from cluster node or locally"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that it could not find the specified deployment.xml file in the local directory. You can omit the --config=deployment.xml and just run "voltdb init" it will generate a default deployment.xml file for you. Then you could proceed to "voltdb start" if you just want a simple standalone instance with the default settings.

Or, if you want to modify the configuration settings, you could run "voltdb init" to get a default configuration, then run "voltdb get deployment" to retrieve the generated deployment.xml file from the voltdbroot directory to the local directory. Then you could delete the voltdbroot directory, modify this deployment.xml file and start over. You could also start over using a deployment file you generate manually or one copied from the examples/HOWTOs/deployment-file-examples folder.

(Disclosure: I work at VoltDB)